# how to take screenshot of IOS phone using react-native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Is it possible to programmatically take a screenshot of the current phone view while the react-native app is in the background? The expo api for takeSnapshotAsync requires a view ref to work. I do not want to capture the actual app itself. I want to capture whatever the user is doing on their phone.

Comment: This sounds illegal

Comment: Why would it be illegal if the user allows it with a permission?

Comment: There isn't a permission for this kind of thing in iOS. The sandbox will prevent you from doing anything like this

Comment: You could potentially read out passwords. U got a use case ?

Comment: it was an app someone asked me if I could make so they could see what their kids were doing. Not trying to create a secret snooping app for North Korea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this one should be able to do what you want: https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

import RNViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";

```
RNViewShot.takeSnapshot(viewRef, {
  format: "jpeg",
  quality: 0.8
})
.then(
  uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
  error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
);
```

Try to call `RNViewShot` in `setInterval` maybe it will work even when the app is minimalized. If `RNViewShot` will not work then you will have to create your own native ios module.